# Table cell text overflow issues

Tags: html, css, html-table

After asking a question about this earlier, I finally figured out the problem specifically. This is the code I am having trouble with:

**CSS**

```
table {
    display: block;
    margin: 30px 0 auto 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1300px;
    text-align: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout:fixed;
}

td {
    max-width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th style="width: 18%;">Col 1</th>
        <th style="width: 12%;">Col 2</th>
        <th style="width: 13%;">Col 3</th>
        <th style="width: 7%">Col 4</th>
        <th style="width: 7%">Col 5</th>
        <th style="width: 6%">Col 6</th>
        <th style="width: 5%">Col 7</th>
        <th style="width: 13%">Col 8</th>
        <th style="width: 16%">Col 9</th>
        <th style="width: 3%">Col 10</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Some</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Stuff</td>
        <td>foo</td>
        <td>bar</td>
        <td>etc</td>
        <td>whatever</td>
        <td>stuff</td>
        <td>Alotofdatakkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Pretty much, I want the long data to be trimmed according to the percent width in the header (16% in this case). Only problem is that this does not work in html5:
(In this image, left is without a  and the right is with one)

[image: http://puu.sh/2T9N7.png]

The left is what I want the data to look like. Now before someone says "just add max-width: 100px; or so" that is something I cannot do. It works fine like that, sure, until you start dealing with percents then max-width magically decides not to work. I also feel like there is an easier way than specifying the max-width on every single cell (left example without html5 doctype proves this as well).

*In short:* I am trying to get text within a cell to be auto cut off with ellipses depending on the width of its corresponding header width.

This is getting pretty annoying because I have been trying to figure this out for hours now so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Mr.Alien Of course it is but that question was not well formatted and I didnt know what the problem was

Comment: I can not answer, but recommend to use the server side characters output limitation.

Comment: @lemondrop We have edit option, you can edit your question

Comment: Seems to work fine with a HTML5 doctype to me http://jsfiddle.net/mKNv3/show/